# Passing values from an Rnw file to an R script

Tags: r, knitr

Since I am a newbie as far as knitr is concerned, I am reading and modifying the examples given in knitr web site. One the approaches that caught my attention is to call chunks of an R script within an Rmw file. After compiling and modifying several examples, I wonder whether one can set a variable on an Rmw file and pass it to an R-script.

Here is an example

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<set-options, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
options(replace.assign=TRUE)
opts_chunk$set(cache=TRUE, fig.show='asis')
read_chunk('simple_example.R')
@

\title{Example}
\author{Somebody}
\maketitle

\section{Print variable}

<<Print-data, echo=TRUE>>=
inp=2
@

\end{document}
```

and

```
# Simple Example

## ---- Print-data ----

inp=inp+2
print(inp)
```

The output result is ip=2 and an error msg "object inp not found".

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code chunk `Print-data` overrode the one in the Rnw file, so `inp=2` was not executed, hence the error.

It seem you want to [embed](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/reference/) the chunk *after* `Print-data`:

```
<<>>=
inp=2
<<Print-data>>
@
```